# jQuery on click call function with parameters

Tags: jquery

When I click on any of the buttons, it tells me showElement is not defined.I'm looking to create a reusable function called showElement which can be called whenever I want to show a div by passing an id of that div. What am I doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/2taswyy6/20/

This is my html:

```
<button onclick="showElement('div1')">
Show Div 1
</button>
<button onclick="showElement('div2')">
Show Div 2
</button>

<div hidden id="div1">Showing Div 1</div>
<div hidden id="div2">Showing Div2</div>
```

updated: This is my jQuery:

```
  function showElement(id){
    $('#'+id).show()
  }
```

Comment: Why is that function within document ready?

Comment: `showElement` is a private function inside the document ready.  It is not on the global scope for the inline bindings to access it.  It will be undefined for the inline bindings.

Comment: @KevinB does it need to be within a document ready?

Comment: @Boki_LV If it doesn't depend on the document being ready, there's no reason to delay defining it.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for providing the links and all your input but I took it out of document ready and it still tells me that it is not defined. See here https://jsfiddle.net/2taswyy6/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="showElement('div1')">
Show Div 1
</button>
<button onclick="showElement('div2')">
Show Div 2
</button>

<div style="display:none" id="div1">Showing Div 1</div>
<div style="display:none" id="div2">Showing Div2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function showElement(id){
  $('#'+id).show()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Use Global data-*

You can use html global data-* on every button as an attribute to identify the id  for the div to be shown.
Here is an example:

HTML:

```html
<button data-div-id="1" class="button">Show Div 1</button>
```

More: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

## Solution:

Here is the solution of your question using jQuery on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/ZrVvOv).

If you want to toggle the div here is another example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/EQGoGM)

## PS:

Change css from **visibility: hidden;** to **display: none;** if you want to hide it totally.

More: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inline function call it is an old method, use a separate function inside your javascript.